# Relationships - Rating one per user per address

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database

Trying to craft a relationship like so:

The combination of `user`/`address` can only have one `rating`, where an `address` is part of a `building` which is also a foreign key on the rating.

At the moment I have this:

```
class Rating(models.Model):  
    buildingaddress = select2.fields.ForeignKey(BuildingAddress, overlay='Select the Building Address')  
    building = select2.fields.ForeignKey(Building, db_column='bin', null=True, overlay='Select your Building')  
    author = select2.fields.ForeignKey(User, overlay='Select the Author')  
    suggestion = models.TextField()  
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This doesn't work correctly at the moment, because it allows multiple ratings per user per address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `unique_together` constraint to make it so every address and user combination has to be unique

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

`unique_together = ('buildingaddress', 'author')`